# Get AWS registered Domains, IPs and hosted-zones

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I want to get the list of all registered resources on an AWS account.
Such as Domains, IPs, hosted-zones
and some metadata regarding that list such as creation_time or expiry_date... etc
What I have done so far:

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f3`; do aws route53domains list-domains --region $region 2>/dev/null; done
```

This returns the list of registered domains.
I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it, for example, using boto3 and also to list the other resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boto3 to retrieve most information from AWS.
Create a profile [Boto3 Credentials](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html), and then just request any service that you want information about through the client interface.

For example, fetching hosted zones and domain names:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='XXXXXXX',region_name='us-west-1')

route53 = session.client('route53')
print(route53.list_hosted_zones()['HostedZones'])

route53domains = session.client('route53domains')
print(route53domains.list_domains())
```

Comment: do you know how to get the list of IPs for all resources and their metadata?

Comment: I also get this exception regarding route53domain
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://route53domains.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/"